# How to get text of <th> tags

Tags: jquery

This seems like it should be straightforward but I can't get it to work.

HTML

```
<table id="mytable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Head1</th>
         <th>Head2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      ..body stuff..
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$("#mytable > thead > tr > th").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).text();
})
```

Console shows "undefined" for each text value.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console? You are just missing a `)`. `console.log($(this).text());`

Answer (score 2):

keep eyes on console .. you have a syntax error `($(this).text()` should be `($(this).text())` you forgot `)`

```js
$("#mytable > thead > tr > th").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Head1</th>
         <th>Head2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      ..body stuff..
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Important** : be sure to include jquery